# Virtual function calling mechanism

Tags: c++, inheritance

```
class base {
public:
  virtual void fn(){}
};


class der: public base {
public:
  void fn(){}
};

der d;

base *b = &d;
b->fn();
```

When the compiler encounters the statement `b->fn(`), the following information is available to the compiler:

1. b is a pointer to the class base,
2. base class is having a virtual function as well as a vptr.

My question is: how does the vptr of class der come into picture at run time?

Comment: Are you asking about a particular implementation of virtual methods, or virtual methods in general as per the standard?

Comment: b is a pointer to d of type base* (not quite the same as your #1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When reasoning about this, it helps me to maintain a clear image of the memory layout of the classes, and in particular to the fact that the `der` object *contains* a `base` subobject that has exactly the same memory layout as any other `base` object.

In particular your `base` object layout will simply contain a pointer to the vtable (there are no fields), and the `base` subobject of `der` will also contain that pointer, only the value stored in the pointer differs and it will refer to the `der` version of the `base` vtable (to make it a bit more interesting, consider that both `base` and `der` did contain members):

```
// Base object         // base vtable (ignoring type info)
+-------------+        +-----------+
| base::vptr  |------> | &base::fn |
+-------------+        +-----------+
| base fields |
+-------------+

// Derived object      // der vtable
+-------------+        +-----------+
| base::vptr  |------> | &der::fn  |
+-------------+        +-----------+ 
| base fields |
+-------------+ <----- [ base subobject ends here ]
| der fields  |
+-------------+
```

If you look at the two drawings, you can recognize the `base` subobject in the `der` object, when you do `base *bp = &d;` what you are doing is obtaining a pointer to the `base` subobject *inside* `der`. In this case, the memory location of the `base` subobject is exactly the same as that of the `base` subobject, but it need not be so. What is important is that the pointer will refer to the `base` subobject, and that the memory pointed to has the memory layout of a `base`, but with the difference that the pointers stored in the object will refer to the `der` versions of the vtable.

When the compiler sees the code `bp->fn()`, it will consider it to be a `base` object, and it knows where the *vptr* is in a `base` object, and it also knows that `fn` is the first entry in the vtable, so it only needs to generate code for `bp->vptr[ 0 ]()`. If `bp` refers to a `base` object then `bp->vptr` will refer to the `base` *vtable* and `bp->vptr[0]` will be `base::fn`. If the pointer on the other hand refers to a `der` object, then `bp->vptr` will refer to the `der` vtable, and `bp->vptr[0]` will refer to `der::fn`.

Note that at compile time the generated code for both cases is exactly the same: `bp->vptr[0]()`, and that it gets dispatched to different functions based on the data stored in the `base` (sub)object, in particular the value stored in `vptr`, which gets updated in construction.

By clearly focusing on the fact that the `base` subobject must be present and *compatible* with a `base` object you can consider more complex scenarios, as multiple inheritance:

```
struct data { 
   int x;
};
class other : public data, public base {
   int y;
public:
   virtual void fn() {}
};
+-------------+
| data::x     |
+-------------+ <----- [ base subobject starts here ] 
| base::vptr  |
+-------------+
| base fields |
+-------------+ <----- [ base subobject ends here ]
| other::y    |
+-------------+
int main() {
   other o;
   base *bp = o;
}
```

This is a more interesting case, where there is another base, at this point the call `base * bp = o;` creates a pointer to the `base` subobject and can be verified to point to a different location than the `o` object (try printing out the values of `&o` and `bp`). From the calling site, that does not really matter because `bp` has static type `base*`, and the compiler can always dereference that pointer to locate `base::vptr`, use that to locate `fn` in the vtable and end up calling `other::fn`.

There is a bit more magic going on in this example though, as the `other` and `base` subobjects are not aligned, before calling the actual function `other::fn`, the `this` pointer has to be adjusted. The compiler resolves by not storing a pointer to `other::fn` in the `other` *vtable*, but rather a pointer to a *virtual thunk* (small piece of code that fixes the value of `this` and forwards the call to `other::fn`)

Comment: @user966379: There's an interesting [link](http://www.lrdev.com/lr/c/virtual.html) that was added as an answer by Luchian Grigore (and then deleted the answer probably because of an unexplained downvote) You should also try to read the [Itanium ABI](http://sourcery.mentor.com/public/cxx-abi/abi.html), that while is not a standard, it is used by some common compilers including gcc. [BTW, the common way of thanking is upvoting, I find it interesting that you have *thanked* a couple of not upvoted answers]

Answer (score 4):

The Holy Standard does not require a vptr or a vptr table. However in practice that’s the only way this is implemented.

So here’s psudo-code for what happens:

1. `a_base_compatible_vtable_ptr = b->__vtable_ptr__`
2. `a_func_ptr = a_base_compatible_vtable_ptr[INDEX_FOR_fn]`
3. `a_func_ptr( b )`

A main insight is that for an object of the `der` class the vtable pointer in the object will point to the `der` class’ vtable, which is *compatible* with the `base` class’ vtable, but contains pointers pointing to the `der` class’ function implementations.

Thus, the `der` implementation of the function is called.

In practice the `this` pointer argument passing in point (3) is typically optimized, special, by passing the `this` pointer in a dedicated processor register instead of on the machine stack.

For more in depth discussion see the literature on C++ memory model, e.g. [Stanly Lippman’s book *Inside the C++ Object Model*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201834545).

Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 1):

In a typical implementation there is only one `vptr` per object. If the object is of type `der` that pointer will point to the `der` vtable, while if it is of type `base` it points to the `base` vtable. This pointer is set upon construction. Something similar to this:

```
class base {
public:
  base() {
    vptr = &vtable_base;
  }
  virtual void fn(){}
protected:
   vtable* vptr;
};


class der: public base {
public:
  der() {
    vptr = &vtable_der;
  }
  void fn(){}
};
```

A call to `b->fn()` does something similar to:

```
vtable* vptr = b->vptr;
void (*fn_ptr)() = vtpr[fn_index];
fn_ptr(b);
```

Comment: how to get fn_index ?

Comment: You don't. You're probably solving the wrong problem

Answer (score 1):

i found the best answer over [Here..](http://compscipleslab.wordpress.com/2012/12/18/the-ins-and-outs-of-c-virtual-functions/)

Answer (score 0):

Vptr is a property of the object, not of the pointer. Therefore the static type of `b` (`base`) does not matter. What does matter is its dynamic type (`der`). The object pointed to by `b` has its vptr pointing to `der`'s virtual method table (vtbl).

When you call `b->fn()`, it's `der`'s virtual method table that gets consulted to figure out which method to call.

Answer (score 0):

The vptr is not "of the class", but of the "instantiated object".
When `d` is constructed, first the space for it is allocated (and contains the vptr as well).

Then `base` is constructed (and the vptr is made pointing to base vtable) and then `der` is constructed around `base`and the vptr is updated to point to the `der` vtable.

Both the `base` and `der` vtables have entries for the `fn()` functions, and since the vptr refer t othe der one, when you call b->fn(), in fact what happens is a call to `vptr(p)[fn_index]()` is called.

But since vptr(p) == vptr(&d), in this case, a call to `der::fn` will results.